# Lock screen doesn't show login option

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-10

On my Windows 10 machine, it boots to the typical lock screen. It shows the power options. On any button combination it changes to a completely empty screen.

How do I get back to the login prompt?

Note there may be an active Remote Desktop session.

Comment: Are you able to boot to safe mode with command prompt and access the built-in admin account?  If not are you able to boot into system recovery and get access to the OS via your normal account?

Comment: @MikeGaruccio No. I searched for this on Windows 10, but most of what I found said this cannot be done now because it boots quickly. None of the options for restarting into safe mode worked.

Comment: Check out [This Link](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10) use option number 3 to create a recovery drive and boot into safe mode that way.  let me know if you are able to get to a cmd prompt

Comment: @MikeGaruccio thanks. When I posted, I could not get past the lock screen. I have since discovered that I can remove desktop into the machine, so I will try to reboot into safe mode with that link. Thanks!!

Comment: Awesome, post back if you have any further issues.